# How to train 3D array in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Code:

```
X_train_=np.random.rand(100,200,16)
y_train_=np.random.rand(100,1)

batch=32

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(batch,200,16)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
    
num_epochs = 10
model.fit(X_train_, y_train_, epochs=num_epochs,batch_size=batch)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 102400 but received input with shape (None, 3200)
```

Comment: You don't need to add batch dimension to input shape. Remove `batch` in your first layer `tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(200,16)),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can use your 3D array with neural Network, First by flattening your 3d array in a 1D array. Second use Convoltional Layer.

In your case you just don't have to include `input_shape()`

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
X_train_=np.random.rand(100,200,16)
y_train_=np.random.rand(100,1)

batch=32

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
    
num_epochs = 10
model.fit(X_train_, y_train_, epochs=num_epochs,batch_size=batch)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
4/4 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.7472 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6948 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6730 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6502 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.6521 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6450 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6276 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6343 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6933 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6119 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fc63f589090>
```